# How do check an array for repeat numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, random, logic

I'm trying to produce an array with 4 random generated [srand seeded rand()] without any repeats. I'm using a for loop to:

Select a position in the array, 
Generate a number, 
Assign the number to the currently highlighted position
Check that the assigned number is not equal to a previous entry, as per the following pseudocode.

```
if no - 
    Then select the next position in the array and generate a new number
if yes -
    Do not move to the next array position and generate a new number again.

repeat until array position 3
```

This was my attempt:

```
int operator_selection;
int operator_index[3];
int random_value;
for (operator_selection = 0; operator_selection < 4; operator_selection++)
{
    random_value = rand() %4 + 1;

    if (random_value = operator_index[0] || operator_index[1] || operator_index[2])
    {
        (operator_selection - 1);
    }
    operator_index[operator_selection] = random_value;
    cout<<operator_index[operator_selection]<<" ";

    if (operator_selection == 3)
    {
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

However when I run the executable I always end up with repeats, so I'm pretty sure the logic behind my first 'if statement' is flawed.

I'm a c++ beginner and this is my 3rd attempt at writing a source file from scratch, so apologies if I've made a silly mistake.

Comment: Use `std::set` if you need to store unique values.

Comment: Besides the condition being incorrectly written, you have undefined behavior. You may not inspect the value of an element before it's assigned. For example, in the first iteration, only `operator_index[0]` is assigned a value, but you then check elements at index 1 and 2. You should rethink your approach to only verify previously defined elements. Additionally, you can be certain that if you assign element 0 a value, than that element's value will be equal to the value you just assigned to it.

Comment: That first if condition doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Fill your array with unique values (not random, 1,2,3 ... is obvious) and then use `std::random_shuffle` to make them random.

Comment: You need to read a good C++ tutorial. There's so many mistakes in the logic that it's not easily fixable in the Q&A format of this site.

Comment: if you need unique random numbers you should not keep rolling numbers until they are unique, as this is rather inefficient and for some edge cases even super inefficient. Construct them such that there cannot be duplicates from the start

Comment: Btw simple way to check if array values are unique: `array_size == std::set( array_begin, array_end ).size()`

Comment: There are multiple bugs, both logical and language bugs in the shown code. "`if (random_value = operator_index[0] || operator_index[1] || operator_index[2])`" -- this is utterly wrong in many fundamental ways. You really need to read a good C++ book. C++ simply doesn't work this way. "`(operator_selection - 1);`" -- this does absolutely nothing, whatsoever. Really: go and read a good C++ book. This code is not salvageable, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I see several problems in your posted code.

**Problem 1**

The line

```
if (random_value = operator_index[0] || operator_index[1] || operator_index[2])
```

does not do what you are hoping to do. You need to use:

```
if ( (random_value == operator_index[0]) || 
     (random_value == operator_index[1]) ||
     (random_value == operator_index[2]) )
```

**Problem 2**

Comparing `random_value` against `operator_index[0]` and `operator_index[1]` and `operator_index[2]` is incorrect. You only need to compare up to `operator_index[operator_selection-1]`.

**Problem 3**

The line

```
(operator_selection - 1);
```

does not change the value of `operator_selection`. It just evaluates the expression and discards the value.

What you need is a statement that decrements the value of `operator_selection`. E.g.

```
--operator_selection;
```

**Problem 4**

You need to continue to the next iteration of the loop when you find an existing value.

---

Here's an updated version of the loop:

```
for (operator_selection = 0; operator_selection < 4; operator_selection++)
{
   random_value = rand() %4 + 1;

   bool matchFound = false;
   for ( int i = 0; i < operator_selection-1; ++i )
   {
      if ( random_value == operator_index[i] )
      {
         matchFound = true;
         break;
      }
   }

   if ( matchFound )
   {    
      --operator_selection;
      continue;
   }

   operator_index[operator_selection] = random_value;
   cout<<operator_index[operator_selection]<<" ";
}

// Move this out of the loop.
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the helps, works exactly how I intended it to now, and thank you for the explanation of the errors. I know it's clunky but Im intending to build off os this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

int main()
{ 
    std::array<int, 4> a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    std::shuffle(a.begin(), a.end(), g);
    for(auto& i : a)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ocHmDjNvTxBzwcPJ)**</kbd>

This version is more readable and more efficient.

**Update:** this does not answer the question as it is and does not fit if it's a home-work. But I would leave it here just in the case OP is interested in a better alternative.

Comment: This may produce the correct results, but does nothing to address the multiple, fundamental problems with the original code, and as such does not really answer the question of what was wrong with the original code, in every way. Which is, of course, is a big task, since pretty much everything was wrong with it. The correct answer here is, really, "read a C++ book".

Comment: i removed my downvote, but agree with Sam, now the answer doesnt really answer the question anymore

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, I agree. Anyway, I will leave it hanging just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick to is to reverse the lopp one step back  if the conditions are not met.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;



int main(void)
{
      const int size=100 ;
      int  arr[100] ;
      int i=0;

      srand(time(0));

      for ( i=0;i<size;i++)   {
          arr[i]=rand() % size;
          for(int j=0; j < i ; j++)  if (arr[j] == arr[i]) i--; 
      }
       cout<<"   \n\n\n ";


      // Loop to display the array arr[ ]
      for (  i=0;i<size;i++) cout<<""<<arr[i]<<"\t";

      cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
      cin.ignore();
      cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 91     71      14      65      12      25      64      98      83      28
99      9       5       0       89      36      95      55      73      90
78      2       52      70      39      63      17      50      7       58
34      84      40      51      20      31      38      32      35      49
61      66      72      92      6       59      41      13      22      23
81      56      1       16      21      62      57      10      11      54
77      86      76      93      4       96      8       33      94      67
29      48      15      82      97      37      26      46      43      80
68      85      60      30      42      53      18      69      45      88
47      79      75      44      24      27      74      3       19      87

Press any key to continue
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make your array bigger. As already mentioned, it would be nicer to use a std::array, but I'll stick with the old style one. You define `operator_index` with a dimension of 3 which only allows for 3 elements (with offsets from 0 to 2). So this needs a dimension of 4.

You should also initialize the contents of the array (or ensure that you never read from uninitialized elements).

Next, for the first random number there is no possibility of a collision. So you can put it directly into the array.

```
operator_index[0] = rand() %4 + 1;
```

You can then loop from 1 to 3 for the remaining 3 entries.

You can even go a little further than this. When you have filled the first 3 entries you can directly calculate the last,

```
operator_index[3] = 10 - operator_index[2] - operator_index[1] - operator_index[0];
```

(the sum from 1 to 4 is 10, so the last element is *10 - the sum of the first three*)

The main problem with your code is this

```
if (random_value = operator_index[0] || operator_index[1] || operator_index[2])
{
    (operator_selection - 1);
}
```

This does an assignment, not an equality check. It is assigned the logical OR of the first 3 elements. Since you do not initialize the array you will be reading garbage, and the result is probably going to be that `random_value` will be set to one and the condition will evaluate to true.

`(operator_selection - 1)` is an operator without side effects. It does not modify `operator_selection`. Also once you have found a duplicate, you want to start your loop again.

Here's a version that minimizes the looping.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    int operator_selection;
    int operator_index[4] = {0};
    int random_value;
    srand(time(0));
    operator_index[0] = rand() %4 + 1;
    for (operator_selection = 1; operator_selection < 3; operator_selection++)
    {
        random_value = rand() %4 + 1;

        if (operator_index[0] == random_value || operator_index[1] == random_value)
        {
            --operator_selection;
            continue;
        }
        operator_index[operator_selection] = random_value;
    }
    operator_index[3] = 10 - operator_index[2] - operator_index[1] - operator_index[0];

    for(auto& elem : operator_index)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

All that said, I still prefer the std::random_shuffle approach, which I would also suggest.